# Flask-Restplus cannot find any route

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

I just started using this library so please correct me if I'm saying something wrong.

From my understanding, blueprint is kind of container for namespaces. For example I want to specify a blueprint for working with global objects (like projects):

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask import Blueprint
from app.global.projects import projects

global= Blueprint('global', __name__)

api = Api (global)

api.add_namespace(projects)
```

I register this blueprint for app:

```
from app.global import global
app.register_blueprint(global, '/global') #<== prefix
```

Then I specify a namespace with routes:

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource, fields

projects = Namespace('projects')

@projects.route('/projects')
class ProjectResource(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {
            'num': 42
        }
```

So, from my understanding, if I send POST to the following url

```
127.0.0.1:5000/global/projects
```

I will have `{'num': 42}`

But I have only 404. Where is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not valid Python syntax (global keywords as a variable name)
so, unfortunately, I could not test it.

But here is a similar working example with `App`, `Blueprints`, `Api`, and `Namespace` working together.

## App

```
# run.py

from flask import Flask
from .api import blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix='')
app.run(debug=True)
```

## Blueprint

```
# api.py

from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Namespace, Resource

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(blueprint)
global_namespace = Namespace('global', path='/global')
api.add_namespace(global_namespace)


@global_namespace.route('/projects')
class ProjectResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'num': 42}
```

## Test

```
$ python run.py
$ ...
$  curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/global/projects
{
   "num": 42
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made my code work after I added "path" to the namespace as you did in your code.